# What's wrong in git init ...?

Tags: command

When I use `git init` it only shows (master) and not (master -> origin), and then that when I use the command:  `git push -u origin master` it returns an error:

`error: src refspec master does not match any.` 
`error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:BghAek/something.git'`

Comment: Try `git push -u origin main`

Comment: This doesn't help...It is sending an error.

Comment: Please look into the answer that I have posted @SomeOne-49. Might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this happened:

### Forget to add the remote repo link

You have created a new repository using the `init` command, but it looks like you forgot to add the link to the remote repository. So do the following:

1. Remove the `.git` file from you local system.
2. Create a clean repository using the following:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "COMMIT MESSAGE"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin REMOTE_REPOSITORY_LINK
git push -u origin main
```

replace `REMOTE_REPOSITORY_LINK` with that of the remote repository link. Remember your are on `main` branch, so as to keep it consistent with the remote branch( read more [here](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-GitHub-renamed-its-master-branch-to-main)).